# Scalable wordpress setup

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, production-environment

Looking for a high availability wordpress cluster which allows for constant consistency.

As many know, the challenge with wordpress lies when it comes down to updating the wordpress engine or its plugins because

1. Updating 1 instance at a time causes inconsitency
2. Updating them both simultaneously makes the site unavailable for a short time.

Can anyone suggest tried and tested solutions which would allow for updates without risking downtime or corruption ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We created a special WordPress cluster for our site that is based on Docker containers and includes:

- NGINX load balancer
- two NGINX PHP servers that are automatically scaled
- replicated master-master MySQL databases
- storage node

To get even higher availability we made two replicas of such cluster, hosted them in two different data centers (one in Europe and the other one in the USA), connected with each other and activated synchronization.

After checking this solution in production for our site, we packaged this cluster for automatic installation and made it publicly [available in GitHub](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/wordpress-cluster).

[Here you can find the article](https://blog.jelastic.com/2017/12/14/wordpress-cluster-automatic-scaling-cloud-hosting-in-containers/) with details and step-by-step instruction on how to get it up and running.

Comment: A short update: a new WordPress cluster package is already available with the following topology: 
- LiteSpeed or NGINX load balancer
- LiteSpeed or NGINX web servers with automatic scaling
- Highly-available MariaDB Galera cluster or master-slave replication
- Redis caching and Shared Storage
- Let’s Encrypt SSL
- Premium CDN integration
- Web Application Firewall
- Layer-7 Anti-DDoS Filtering
- WordPress Multisite Networking

Guide on how to install this new WP cluster https://jelastic.com/blog/wordpress-hosting-enterprise-high-availability-auto-scaling/